# Chrome debugging tool Sthetho is not working properly in Mac Os (mojave)

Tags: android, debugging, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am using Sthetho, the Database debugging tool from chrome to see my database from Android device. When I migrated to Mac Os (Mojave v10.14) With Chrome (Version 72.0.3626.119 (Official Build) (64-bit)).

My problem is, I can't query inside the database. The issue is when I click Enter button the cursor goes to the next line instead of executing the query. I can't find any button or menu to do the same.

Any help would be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://crbug.com/929636 - this could be a Stetho's fault so maybe go check their support site.